# Holding Quartz scheduler to trigger job again till previous job finish processing

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler to schedule the process of file download from SFTP. 
The job triggered after every 2 hrs. But sometimes due to huge file size, downloading 
takes more time and before it completes, the process is restarted. Is their any way we 
can hold the scheduler to trigger same job again till the previous process completes processing?

I m using quartz 1.8.5.
Below is code

```
<flow name="quartzCronModel">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Quartz"
        jobName="cron-job" cronExpression="${database_download_timer}"
        encoding="UTF-8">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component doc:name="Download Database"
        class="com.org.components.sftp.FileTransfer">
        <method-entry-point-resolver
            acceptVoidMethods="true">
            <include-entry-point method="execute" />
        </method-entry-point-resolver>
    </component>
</flow>
```

I am reading cron expression from a properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Your job will need to implement the [StatefulJob](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/1.8.5/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html) interface. It is a marker interface that tells Quartz that it should not trigger the job if it is still running. In other words it prevents concurrent executions of the job.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you please send me an example.

Comment: Google "quartz statefuljob example" and you will get lots of examples. For example, this one should be useful: https://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/stateful-jobs-using-quartz-scheduler/

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since this question was asked. Jan Moravec has answered correctly, but during this time, this class has been deprecated. According to the Quartz documentation, It is currently best to use @DisallowConcurrentExecution and/or @PersistJobDataAfterExecution annotations instead.
I hope it will be useful